# How to access an azure storage blob as if it were a local file?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to "mount" a file for read/write access? I realize that I can GetBlobReference and BlobStream but what if I just want to give a file path to a library that doesn't understand Azure?

One example: A "Logger" library that just appends text to a specified file in some fashion.
Another (more realistic) example: Datasource for .sdf (sql server compact 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mount a page blob as an NTFS file system using XDrive.  See [this blog post](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/02/02/Using-Windows-Azure-Drive-%28aka-X-Drive%29.aspx).

Comment: This looks promising. I'll see if I can get that working in my web role.

Answer (score 2):

As Oliver says you can use XDrive for this - but if you do this then please consider that only one role instance can have write access to the drive - so it's not a good solution for load balanced SQL CE.

For the logger scenario, you could also consider using some algorithm on "paged blobs" - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691964.aspx. This won't be "normal file access", but could be used across multiple roles and role instances.

Comment: You bring up a good point. I only use one role at a time so I should be ok for now. I should probably be using SQL azure but there is a $10/mo charge to get another db even if it is just for staging.